# Using a non-static method without referring it to an object?

Tags: java, object, methods

```
public class Appointment{
    public TimeInterval getTime();
    {/*implementation not shown*/}

    public boolean conflictsWith(Appointment other)
    {
     return getTime().overlapsWith(other.getTime());
    }
}

public class TimeInterval{
    public boolean overlapsWith(TimeInterval interval)
    {/*implementation not shown*/}
}
```

My question lies with the `return getTime().overlapsWith(other.getTime())` statement.`getTime()` is not a static method, so I think it can only be used when it is referring to an object. But from that statement, no object is being referred to. I understand that `getTime()` returns an object for the subsequent methods but what about itself? My classmate offers an explanation stating that "when we want to use the `conflictsWith()` method, we would declare an object, thus the return statement would be equivalent to `return object.getTime().overlapsWith(other.getTime()）;`" Is this explanation correct? So does that mean when we use a non-static method inside a method, no object is needed to be referred to?

Answer (score 6):

Since `getTime()` is not a static method, it's invoked on the current object.  The implementation is equivalent to

```
public boolean conflictsWith(Appointment other)
{
  return this.getTime().overlapsWith(other.getTime());
}
```

You'd only invoke `conflictsWith()` on an `Appointment` object, like this:

```
Appointment myAppt = new Appointment();
Appointment otherAppt = new Appointment();
// Set the date of each appt here, then check for conflicts
if (myAppt.conflictsWith(otherAppt)) {
  // Conflict
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When calling a non-static method, the object `this` is implied. At runtime the `this` object refers to the instance of the object that is being operated on. In your case, it refers to the object for which the outer method was called.

Comment: Thank you jeremy, but I have more questions: 1.Does that mean I could neglect using an object when I am using a method inside a method? 2. what is 'this' referred to? A hidden object of this class? I am sorry if these are really simple.

Comment: `this` is a keyword, which acts as an object reference, and which refers to the object instance you are in.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Appointment, getTime() is equivalent to this.getTime().

Your conflictsWith could be rewritten that way:

```
TimeInterval thisInterval = this.getTime(); // equivalent to just getTime()
TimeInterval otherInterval = object.getTime();
return thisInterval.overlapsWith(otherInterval);
```